# Simplify Binomial Function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following input

```
Assuming[
   (n ∈ Integers) && (n > 0) && (k ∈ Integers) && (k >= 0) && (k <= n), 
   FullSimplify[Binomial[n, k]/Binomial[n, k + 1]]
]
```

returns

```
Binomial[n,k]/Binomial[n,k+1]
```

Why does it not give

```
(k+1)/(n-k)
```

and how do I make it do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `FunctionExpand`:

```
FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, k]/Binomial[n, 1 + k]]    
  (1 + k)/(-k + n)
```

*Mathematica*'s understanding of what is simple is based on leaf count and can be unintuitive at times.

Comment: perfect, thanks Searke

Comment: LeafCount indeed gets you a complexity of 11 for both terms. Using the written size of the expression with `ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength@ToString[#] &)]` still yields the same result, though `FullSimplify` now delivers the version that the OP wants.

Comment: Somehow, I have never considered StringLength as a ComplexityFunction until now.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to proceed would be to make `Binomial` more expensive (or less simple) using a `ComplexityFunction`:

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Binomial, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]

FullSimplify[Binomial[n, k]/Binomial[n, k + 1], ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

gives

```
(1 + k)/(-k + n)
```

Comment: Sounds, erm, complex. But it is interesting and good to know.

Comment: It is interesting, that `Simplify[Binomial[n, k]/Binomial[n, 1 + k], ComplexityFunction -> f]` with your definition for `f` gives `Binomial[n, k]/Binomial[n, 1 + k]`. It looks like `Simplify` does not try enough transformations of `Binomial`.

Comment: Probably. You could perhaps find out using another recent Q+A of mine http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/how-can-i-see-which-transformations-simplify-attempts/

Comment: @WalkingRandomly It is overkill `100 Count...`, `1 Count...` is good enough, +1.